# Emacs Autocomplete: the function `define-package` is not known

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, homebrew, emacs24

I am trying to install autocomplete mode on OS X 10.8.4 using emacs 24 installed through brew.

I have cloned autocomplete through git [git mirror here](https://github.com/m2ym/auto-complete) and I'm following the build instructions [build instructions here](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Downloads). I am getting an error during make install telling me that define-package (presumably some elisp) is undefined.

```
➜  auto-complete git:(master) make install
emacs -Q -L . -batch -l etc/install 
Install to: ~/.emacs.d/
Installing to ~/.emacs.d/ from /Users/f/src/auto-complete/

In toplevel form:
auto-complete-config.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: popup

In end of data:
auto-complete-pkg.el:5:1:Warning: the function `define-package' is not known
    to be defined.
Wrote /Users/f/src/auto-complete/auto-complete-pkg.elc

In toplevel form:
auto-complete.el:51:1:Error: Cannot open load file: popup
83117999910111511510211710810812132105110115116971081081011003310106510010032116104101321021111081081111191051101033299111100101321161113212111111711432461011099799115581010409710010045116111451081051151163239108111971004511297116104323412647461011099799115461004734411040114101113117105114101323997117116111459911110911210810111610145991111101021051034110409799459911111010210510345100101102971171081164110
```

Anybody encounter this before / have a fix?

Comment: After perusing some more on this it seems that this may be a missing library issue w.r.t popup (http://www.emacswiki.org/PopUp)

Comment: The text you quote includes 2 "Error"s and one "Warning", so why do you choose to put the warning in the title of your question?

Comment: I think you'd be better of using [MELPA](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MELPA) package manager. Autocomplete is certainly available there. It also looks like its Makefile is trying to install using MELPA routine.

Answer (score 4):

Install using Melpa or Marmalade via `package.el`. Auto-complete expects to be installed this way, and you'll also get updates installed very easily.

If you don't have `package.el` configured already, add the following to `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(setq package-archives 
      '( 
        ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
        ("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
        ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ))

(package-initialize) ;; init elpa packages
```

Just run `M-x package-list-packages` (or `M-x p-l-p TAB`) and install auto-complete from the package list, mark packages with `i` use `x` to run the installation of marked packages.

Periodically, opening `M-x package-list-packages` and pressing `U` will mark installed packages for updating, press `x` to run the updates.

<sup>This is assuming Emacs 24.</sup>